# Tramsformar divs com tamanhos e posiçoes fixos em conteudo responsiva

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, mapas

Amigos, estou no meio de um trabalho de viés acadêmico, e tenho como missão transformar esse mapa em conteúdo virtual e responsivo. 
[image: mapa]

Para isso já tenho uma estrutura de *divs* gerada pelo próprio *Photoshop*. A minha duvida é como transformar isso em conteúdo responsivo? Desde já agradeço a compreensão.

```
<html>
<head><style>
    .mainMap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 14;
        max-width: 100%;

}
.Preenchimento6 {
  background-image: url("img/part1.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 697px;
  top: 1203px;
  width: 288px;
  height: 316px;
  z-index: 13;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.Preenchimento2 {
    background-image: url("img/part2.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 709px;
  top: 908px;
  width: 438px;
  height: 316px;
  z-index: 12;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.Preenchimento3 {
    background-image: url("img/part3.png");

  position: absolute;
  left: 565px;
  top: 512px;
  width: 781px;
  height: 717px;
  z-index: 11;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Preenchimento1 {
    background-image: url("img/part4.png");

  position: absolute;
  left: 1040px;
  top: 614px;
  width: 305px;
  height: 261px;
  z-index: 10;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Preenchimento4 {
    background-image: url("img/part5.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 514px;
  top: 299px;
  width: 226px;
  height: 228px;
  z-index: 9;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.Preenchimento5 {
    background-image: url("img/part6.png");
  position: absolute;
  left: 162px;
  top: 333px;
  width: 905px;
  height: 583px;
  z-index: 8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"></head>
<body>

    <div class="mainMap container">
        <div class="Preenchimento1"></div>
        <div class="Preenchimento2"></div>
        <div class="Preenchimento3"></div>
        <div class="Preenchimento4"></div>
        <div class="Preenchimento5"></div>
        <div class="Preenchimento6"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Comment: Faça o mapa com SVG ao invés de imagens. A propósito: [mapa do Brasil svg](https://github.com/felipeduardo/mapa-brasil-svg).

Comment: Com jQuery eu consegui fazer responsivo. Veja o JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5a2h446/ . Copie o código do Fiddle e crie um arquivo .html no seu computador para testar, porque no Fiddle não fica legal pra visualizar.

Comment: Como eu não tenho as imagens, coloquei uma cor de fundo em cada `div` para ter uma ideia de como fica.